# gcc internals: calculating instruction costs

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

I'm working on a gcc backend for an architecture. The architecture has instructions for indexed array access; so, `ld r0, (r1, r2)` is equivalent to `r0 = r1[r2]` where `r1` is a `int32_t*`.

I'm representing this in the `.md` file with the following pattern:

```
(define_insn "*si_load_indexed"
  [
    (set
      (match_operand:SI 0 "register_operand" "=r")
      (mem:SI
        (plus:SI
          (mult:SI
            (match_operand:SI 1 "register_operand" "%r")
            (const_int 4))
          (match_operand:SI 2 "register_operand" "r"))))
  ]
  ""
  "ld %0, (%2, %1)"
  [(set_attr "length" "4")]
)
```

However, the instruction is never actually being emitted. Looking at the debug output from the instruction combining stage, I see this:

```
Trying 8, 9 -> 10:
Successfully matched this instruction:
(set (reg:SI 47 [ *_5 ])
    (mem:SI (plus:SI (mult:SI (reg/v:SI 43 [ b ])
                (const_int 4 [0x4]))
            (reg:SI 0 r0 [ a ])) [2 *_5+0 S4 A32]))
rejecting combination of insns 8, 9 and 10
original costs 8 + 4 + 4 = 16
replacement cost 32
```

If I've read this correctly, it indicates that the instruction pattern has been matched, but the instruction has been rejected due to being more expensive than the original instructions.

So, how is it calculating the cost of my instruction? Where's it getting that 32 from (which seems weirdly high)? How do I persuade gcc to actually use this instruction?

Comment: How did you resolve this? I have the same issue and need to
define cost for a new instruction with a similar pattern above

Comment: I didn't. I gave up and used LLVM. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The proper place to asked questions like this is gcc@gcc.gnu.org. They're very helpful if you ask intelligent questions. :)

You should read the Internals Manual first, of course. The relevant section is here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Costs.html#Costs

I believe you need to look at `TARGET_RTX_COSTS`, but I could be wrong. The default behaviour is to estimate the cost by stepping through the RTL recursively and adding up the operations, I think, but it's convoluted and a while since I looked at it (look at `rtx_costs`).

Other ports add instruction attributes to help them judge costs.

Comment: Yes, I've been reading that, but I've found it very puzzling --- surely the cost of an instruction depends on the instruction selected, and not the RTL that the instruction represents? Right now I have all the costing infrastructure set to the default, but _something_ isn't working right... what I'd really like is to be able to set the cost for each instruction manually in the `define_insn` clause, the way I do for lengths, but haven't found a way to do this yet.

Comment: Bear in mind that some define_insn are meta-instructions that get split later.

Comment: Look at other ports. They typically have an attribute to split the instructions into groups or classes or whatever. They then use those attributes in the costs calculation. They prefer not to use absolute numbers because costs vary between processor variants.