# fuse multiple insns into a single new insn

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

I need to fuse multiple instructions into a single one.

...

r1 = (r1) op1 (const)

...

...

r1 = (r1) op2 (r2)

...

...

r3 = op3 (r1)

...

I defined a peephole2 pattern in my GCC backend .md file. If these
three instructions are contiguous, then I do get my test "testnew"
instruction. If these instructions are far apart, I dont.

```
(define_peephole2
  [(set (match_operand:DI 0 "register_operand" "")
    (op1:DI (match_dup 0) (match_operand:SI 1 "immediate_operand" "") ))
  (set (match_dup 0)
    (op2:DI (match_operand:DI 2 "register_operand" "") (match_dup 0)))
  (set (match_dup 0)
    (sign_extend:DI (op3:SI (match_dup 0))))]
  "TARGET_MYCORE"
  [(set (match_dup 0) (sign_extend:DI (op3:SI (op2:SI (op1:SI
(match_dup 0) (match_dup 1)) (match_dup 0)))))]
  "")

(define_insn "*testnew"
  [(set (match_operand:DI 0 "register_operand" "=d")
        (sign_extend:DI (op3:SI (op2:SI (op1:SI (match_dup 0)
(match_operand:SI 1 "immediate_operand" "I")) (match_dup 0)))))]
  "TARGET_MYCORE"
  "testnew 36"
  [(set_attr "mode" "DI")])
```

How can I fuse multiple instructions that are far apart into a new
single opcode that MYCORE has ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this on the gcc-help mailing list and got very satisfactory answers to unblock myself. Summarizing here for posterity.

In nutsehll, GCC's combine will take care of such "fusions" provided you teach it the required patterns. define_peephole is used when there  is no obvious dataflow between insns.

To know what patterns you need to define :

- Take a look at the .combine rtl dump (generated by -O -da)
- You will see some debug dumps of the format for insns that it is trying to fuse :

> Trying Num1, Num2 -> Num3 :
>   Failed to match this instruction:   ... ...

- Define a define_insn pattern that will match the above
- You may also need to update some rtx_costs and make your new instruction cheaper than the set of instructions being replaced
  (target_rtx_costs hook). Only then GCC favors your new instruction
  over the original set of instructions being fused.

and embed a define_insn pattern in your backend's machine description file.

I found a define_insn pattern which is useful for those attempting a similar task [gcc internals: calculating instruction costs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529822/gcc-internals-calculating-instruction-costs)